# Exceptions thrown when starting MVC Project (although project works fine)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am pressing F5 to run an MVC project and I've noticed a lot of exceptions in the Output window:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Out of curiosity, I've pressed `CTRL-ALT-E`, to open the Exception Settings and I've checked the

> System.FormatException

so that the last 4 exceptions would be hit, and here's what I got, on the `_Layout.cshtml`:

[image]

Why do I get these exceptions?

Should I be bothered by them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be bothered by them!

Probably one of the entries in your bundles configuration is not correct. In:

```
App_Start\BundleConfig.cs
```

You may have:

```
ScriptBundle javascriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Javascript");
javascriptBundle.Include(
    "~/Scripts/somefile.js",
...
```

And one of the files is wrong.

Comment: Found the culprit. It's "~/Scripts/ej/common/ej.unobtrusive.min.js". I am baffled! The file exists and it is used in the bundling, otherwise the syncfusion grid wouldn't be working. But this line exactly throws the error. Am I left with no option but to ignore this Exception?

Answer (score 0):

As @steve said check in your bundle configuration and try importing the below namespace in your view page

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
```